# Commit on master, automatic merge development to said master, why?

Tags: git, tfs, branching-and-merging

I have a strange situation:

I did a commit(the top blue dot in the first image) on my master branch (by accident), however, when I checked TFS I notice that before my commit got added to the main branch, an (automatic?) merge (the highlighted line) happened that included some merges from dev that weren't supposed to be taken.

**Why did this happen?**

[image: See the highlighted line]

A bigger picture shows that after my adjustment, everything got merged together. including the prior merge.
This created issues because the development adjustments weren't ready yet.

[image: Bigger picture]

Comment: I cannot speak to/for TFS but the highlighted line reads `Merge branch 'development' of <url>`, and you get such a merge when you ask for it by running `git pull` which means "run `git fetch`, then run `git merge` unless I told you in advance to run `git rebase` instead". I recommend avoiding `git pull`: break it into its two separate component commands, so that you know what you are asking for, when, and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, TFS will not do any auto merge action. Suggest you compare the author of the specific committer a811648b, if it's not you.

This could be someone else do the git pull in his local repo. If it's you, have you do the pull action before you do the commit, which maybe the root cause.

Just as torek said in comment, `pull` , which is a combined command that does a `fetch` and then a `merge`. More details please take a look at this tutorial-- [Fetch and merge with pull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/repos/git/pulling?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio#fetch-and-merge-with-pull)